# Com a linguagem python eu consigo criar jogos de plataforma qualquer tipo de jogo com python?

Tags: python

Eu queria saber ser com a linguagem de programação python eu consigo criar qualquer tipo de jogo

Comment: importante se concentrar na primeira versão da pergunta, editando-a se necessário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/591449/#comment1028552_591449 - para evitar descentralização de informações, o campo de comentários foi desativado aqui, mas está disponível no post linkado.